# Turning on AWS WAF geolocation restriction

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I have a nodejs API running on an EC2 provisioned by Elastic Beanstalk, in Sydney region.

I setup a Cloudfront distribution to this Elastic Beanstalk.

I would like to protect my API by using AWS WAF by turning AWS WAF geolocation restriction, say to allow Australia only to be able to access the API.

What I am not sure is if I have a few Lambdas (in Sydney as well) that call to this API, will the calls be blocked when I turn WAF on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CloudFront has its own feature of Geo restriction, you don't need WAF(except you need to Whitelist IP addresses on CloudFront).
2. If the lambda in SYD region is making a request to the API, it will be allowed if you whitelisted Australia in CloudFront.
   Basically Lambda falls in Ec2 IP range category.

Additionally, you can launch your Lambda function in VPC and whitelisted the NAT gateway IP in the WAF whitelist on top of Geo rule.